# Using return to get file/document

Tags: javascript, html

As title, i know that return statement can be used to retrieve value and expression from another function to a function. But what i want to know is, can return be used to retrieve document/file type object from a function to another function?

Because i'm doing a webpage using drag and drop, with multiple input on it. One of the input is a checkbox, that will trigger a function when checked. The function will then retrieve value from the checkbox input, as well as the files from DnD function, and pass it to another function.

To make it short, the code looks something similar to this

```
function DnDHandler(){
//Handles the DnD event
return file;
}

function checkboxHandler(value){
//Triggered when the checkbox from webpage is checked
var file = DnDHandler();

//Pass value and file to another function
anotherFunction(value, file);
}
```

I got everything ok, except retrieving the file from DnDHandler function, where it kept showing me the error cannot read property [0] of undefined whenever i tried to get the file data such as name and size. I can get the name and size though using normal passing method, but when i use return statement to get the file, it just doesn't give me any output at all.

So here i am wondering, if i am using return statement in a wrong way? I know it can be used to return value or expression from one function to another function, but can it be used to return a file/document from one function to another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return a file or a document in a javascript function.

To give the other function access to the file you would have to send the location of the file as a string (For example "C:/Program Files/file.txt"), and have that function read the document.

Another solution would be to read the properties of the file inside the DnDHandler() function and send the properties you need.

Comment: Ah thanks.. well i guess i just have to make the file as a global variable, so that it can be accessed by all functions then.